# Access denied when deleting file

Tags: c#, asp.net, file

I have a service (****.svc file) that saves images in the application folder.

When I try to delete another image file (that not in use) from this folder I get "Access to the path '' is denied".

```
foreach (string file in Directory.GetFiles(serverPath))
{
       File.Delete(file);
}
```

Do you have any idea why I can write to this folder but can't delete from it?

Comment: check if it is opened in background,use taskmanager

Comment: My best guess is that the file is in use. Writing just creates new (not in use) files, so that's why that works and deleting doesn't.

Comment: and recheck arguments while saving file .Maybe you are restricting its re use  .

Comment: Can the same user delete the file manually, without elevating permissions with UAC?

Comment: The file is simply in use by another Thread, try to check this

Comment: Do you have permission to delete files from that folder?

Comment: Seems the file might be used / opened by some other process. Pls check it

Comment: You need to check the permissions of the folder

Comment: The file is not in use. I also try to put file that was never in used but the access when deleting is still denied

Comment: You can edit the file directory Sharing just to check the "permissions" of your application. Share the folder with Everyone and check if it's working. Then you may figure out more.

Comment: Please tell me where are you running your service, in IIS or is it some kind of self-hosted windows service? It can have impacts on the privileges, I can explain and add detail only when knowing how you run the service.

Comment: I dont know exactly, I think it self-hosted windows service

Comment: I believe you having privileges to delete does not imply that the application has these privileges, as It might be run from different user, e.g. if it would be IIS hosted, you would have to add `IUSR` and corresponding user privileges (eg. sometimes `NT AUTHORITY\NETWORKSERVICE`), now I suppose you have to discover, which account runs the self-hosted service for you and double check it has granted privileges for deletion in app folder. You can use  `ManagementObjectSearcher` for that. I would first make sure you are correct on this one, before observing other possibilities. Code upon request

Comment: Navigate to the folder, right-click, chose Properties, click the Sharing tab, click Share, chose Everyone from the dropdown, click Add, set the Permission Level to Read/Write in front of Everyone and click Share button. This is just a way to check if you need to elevate any permission. If you do need to do that, it should be made as @jmodrak has described.

Comment: @Ghukas yes, maybe simpler way to detect, wheter it is privileges, but after you are done, it is wise to remove the Everyone permission again.... good advise, +1

Comment: If I share the folder to everyone, I can delete the files!!

Comment: Good news, now remove the sharing and try elevating the service permissions :)

Comment: Ok. If I give EveryOne permission to modify- It work...Thank you!!! But why it's not enuogh to give permission to the specific user?

Comment: @Efrat I wrote an answer for you, check it ;)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So the answer to your question obviously is, the service is run by different user account than the user account, that is logged in with the system.

This is a common issue on WindowsServer platform, that you have to grant the IIS-hosted application privileges for the `IUSR` account.

Go, detect, which account is running the service, e.g. use ManagementObjectSearcher for that.

This A.Moore's code from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/300449/) does the trick

```
ManagementObjectSearcher Processes = new ManagementObjectSearcher("SELECT * FROM Win32_Process");
    foreach (ManagementObject Process in Processes.Get())
    {
        if (Process["ExecutablePath"] != null)
        {
             string ExecutablePath = Process["ExecutablePath"].ToString();
             string[] OwnerInfo = new string[2];
             Process.InvokeMethod("GetOwner", (object[])OwnerInfo);
             Console.WriteLine(string.Format("{0}: {1}", System.IO.Path.GetFileName(ExecutablePath), OwnerInfo[0]));
        }
     }
```

From this, you see which user runs your service, grant it correct privileges and problem is solved ;)

EDIT: create a simple console application for this purpose, you have to manually add reference to `System.Management` and add using for this namespace for it to work, if you are confident enough.

It yields all processes, but you can even modify the query, to only work for your application's process name, however I find it sufficient this way.

Answer (score 2):

try this :

```
FileInfo fi = new FileInfo(FileName); 
if (fi.IsReadOnly) 
      fi.IsReadOnly = false; 
fi.Delete();
```

Comment: For what I know, read only doesn't affect deleting.

Comment: ReadOnly attribute prevents you to do any modification so no deletion too

Comment: @PatrickHofman No it does affects

Comment: The file is not readonly...the code not enter to the if statement

Comment: Verify the attribute of the folder

Comment: I mean the security permission of the folder for your current user ==> check if you have the permission to modify/delete

Comment: I have permission to modify...I dont see permission for delete...

Comment: The most relevant answer ever! Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Have you used "using" when creating FileStreams to write a file, or have you explicitly called close() on the stream /writer instances ? If neither the first nor the last, then a file accessed may remain locked until the garbage collector cleans up those instances that have gone out of scope...

Comment: I use "using" when creating the FileStream

Comment: Insightful.. Thank you..