# How to get apps(processes) per user on a terminal server?

Tags: c#, .net, taskmanager

Is it possible to get the running apps per user on a terminal server? I can get all background processes with `System.Diagnostics.GetProcesses()` but this is not what I want. I would like to get something similar to the Users tab in the Task Manager.

Comment: Did u check https://stackoverflow.com/questions/300449/how-do-you-get-the-username-of-the-owner-of-a-process

Comment: I think I am stumped. I tried Daniels link (thanks)  and it works on my local computer as I am administrator. But the idea was to have a sort of dashboard on the managers computer but he is no administrator. Without being admin I can't get the name.